# Динамические имена свойств в C#

Tags: c#, property

Скажите пожалуйста, C#-программисты, в какой-либо новой версии языка не появилась ли возможность сделать **что-то вроде**:

```
public string name{ get{...} set{...} }
...
obj.property("name") = "Вася";
Console.WriteLine(obj.property("name");
```

на уровне языка (без предпроцессорных или иных приблуд). То есть динамически образовывалось строка с именем свойства, без дополнительного задания соответствия вроде MapProperty(name,"name"); (или чего то **в этом духе**)

Comment: `Пропераций`? определитесь.

Но если такое нужно, то рекомендую посмотреть на питон. Там это возможно.

Comment: Оно так и называется - свойства. или "проперти", но это уже жаргон. "Свойство" - достаточно принятое.

Comment: (1) Это учебная задача? Не представляю себе, для чего обращение к полю по имени нужно в production-коде. Для чего вообще пользователю знать, как называются поля в объекте? (2) Почему не завести `Dictionary<string, string>` вместо этого? Зачем вам класс?

Comment: @asianirish: А всё же, если ваш класс — не более, чем контейнер ключей/значений _без семантики_, почему не dictionary внутри с кастомной логикой сеттера? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx Заодно и проблем с добавлением/удалением в рантайме не будет

Comment: @asianirish: У вас, понятно, при таком подходе не может быть строгой типизации, если свойство известно лишь в runtime. (Как, в частности, нет её и в js.) Вы всё же не описали задачу, а описали лишь ваш подход к её решению. В частности, на текущий момент неясно: (1) в какой момент известны все ключи? (2) как определяется тип данных для каждого данного ключа? Эти знания внутренние для программы и неизменны, или задаются пользователем? (3) почему представление данных для пользователя ссылается на имена ключей? Какая семантика данных?

---
Кстати, через reflection вы также получите лишь `object`.

Comment: Я не стал разжёвывать ответ, так как не вижу ответы даже на те вопросы, которые задал товарищ @VladD.
Что касается "нормально для многих языков" - Вы абсолютно не правы, каждый язык для своих целей. Если в ассемблере не было циклов, это не значит, что он ущербен. Я довольно много работаю с языками без типизации и счастья от этого, ой, как не много. Велосипеды это здорово, конечно, но что-то мне подсказывает, что Ваш выбор в пользу рефлексии ошибочен. Хотелось бы всё-таки услышать ответ на то, для каких целей используется рефлексия в данном случае и чем неприемлемы те же словари.

Comment: По поводу ответа на вопрос мне казалось я ответил выше ("я думал сделать через кастомный индексатор..."), ну, конечно без детализации и как раз таки не увидел каких либо серьезных возражений кроме новых вопросов. Но самое главное не то, чтобы я настаивал на использовании PropertyInfo, например, меня в вопросе интересовало как реализовать на шарпе (который изучаю) идею obj.property("name") = "Вася";, если это можно сделать хорошо с помощью словарей или индексаторов я не против, но вижу что 1. решение не вполне устраивает. 2. Принял ответ Сергея Цаплина потому что это был един-ный подх-й ответ.

Comment: @asianirish: Нет-нет, вы рассказываете о технических методах вашего решения, а интересно, какая семантика вашего класса. Какую задачу вы решаете с точки зрения пользователя? Просто "редактирование пар имя/значение" — согласитесь, нетипичная задача, наверняка эти объекты представляют какие-нибудь автомобили или ракеты, там. Если вы это нам скажете (мы упорно добиваемся этого уже второй день), будет понятно, какого рода гибкость вам нужна. Вы покамест требуете гибкости, несовместимой с type safety (ну, как в js). Исходя из опыта, скорее всего вам нужно не это.

Comment: Это класс узла (Node) распределенной вычислительной сети "черные шахматы" - мой давнишний проект. Значения некоторых проперций исчисляется по связям объекта-узла или породивших его объектов (породивших в терминалогии "черных шахмат", тут долго объяснять). Изначально делал на срр, сначала использовал для хранения отдельных класс Property и их std::map и единый механизм доступа как хранимым, так и вычисляемым, но не уровня языка. Когда стал изучать шарп, узнал про Свойства, и подумал - это то что доктор прописал, отсюда и вопрос о возможностях языка - можно ли реализовать идею легко и элегантно

Comment: P.S. в первоначальных пояснениях я пытался объяснить почему мне нужны эти возможности, так как, как мне кажется, смысловая наполненность класса этого не разъясняет и можно абстрагироваться от конкретного воплощения, достаточно иметь развитое воображения, чтобы представить сотню ситуаций, при которых такое свойство языка было-бы полезным
P.P.S С Днем Победы! Слава народу-победителю!

Comment: @asianirish: (1) Хорошо, здесь понятно. Непонятно, зачем для узла вычислительной сети обращение к его полю (а не к целому _узлу_) _по имени_, тем более добавление _полей_ в рантайме. Если это нужно для _отладки_ (например, сбросить дамп состояния объекта для наблюдения), отражение может быть правильным путём, хотя я бы просто перегрузил `ToString`.

Comment: @asianirish: (2) Мой опыт подсказывает, что динамический доступ не нужен почти никогда. Сущности, которые представляются классами, имеют фиксированную структуру. Пример: `Student` имеет поля `string Name`, `DateTime BirthDate`, `Chair Chair`, `ICollection<Course> TakenCourses` и т. д. Обращение с `Name` никогда не такое же, как с `TakenCourses`, поэтому имея в рантайме лишь _имя_ поля, я не знаю, что с ним в принципе можно/нужно делать. Поэтому гибкость, о которой вы говорите, в описанном примере в принципе не нужна и даже вредна. PS: С Днём Победы!

Comment: Отлично, есть описание задачи. Как уже написал @VladD, динамический доступ вещь довольно редкая. Например, на данный момент я работаю с одной старой СУБД, для которой нет возможности прикрутить ни одну из существующих ORM, поддержки ODBC даже нет в нашем случае. Попытки сделать что-то самостоятельно свелись к хранению некоего заложенного количества известных типов, с которыми предстоит работать, а также небольшого описания специфических моментов. Но, в конце-концов, для любой модели у нас есть завершённое представление о полях, так как добавление чего-то в рантайме ну никак логику не напишет.

Comment: Я сам большой сторонник универсальных вещей, но попытки сделать что-то совсем универсально заканчиваются строительством велосипедов, так как пытаешься решить множество проблем, с которыми уже сталкивались до тебя, а ещё чаще получается так, что некое универсальное решение не находит применения в вашей же собственной задаче. Время и силы потрачены, но получается, что впустую.

Comment: "Узлом" сети (вернее, разновидностью Задачи") может быть человек - для решения невичислимых и NP-полных задач внутри решаемой проблемы и ему надо дать человекочитаемые названия, чтоб он понимал логику отношений. Нарушать фиксированную структуру тоже надо (подумал, может не надо, да нет, вижу что надо). Кроме того, если возможность рефлексии в языке и ОРМ (например), для чего то же их реализовали? Для БОЛЬШИНСТВА задач, да, это не нужно, но ИНОГДА может понадобится. Сеть тоже не универсальна (согласен что не следует делать универсально лишь из чувства перфекционизма, без практического смысла).

Comment: @asianirish: ну, рефлексия нужна, навскидку, для реализации плагинной системы или там сериализации. Хорошо, а какие операции выполняет узел? Всё ещё непонятно, для чего нужен доступ к свойствам узла по имени.

Comment: Я ж уже говорил. Пользователь вводит человекоориентированные команды и в них имена свойств (в том числе). Конечно же команда set name=Vasya age=37 add property(status,STATUS) понятнее чем set property(3)=Vasya add property(int) (к примеру). (Свойства узла не ограниченны хранением полей, значения порождаемых узлов могут рекурсивно зависеть от самого себя и для разрешения требуется человек как часть системы, который решает несложную (для человека) "головоломку", даже если задача абстрактна, удобно использовать в именах зацепки с аналогией реального мира, отражающие относительные качества узлов)

Comment: @asianirish: отлично, для той задачи, которую вы описали, прекрасно подойдёт `Dictionary<string, object>` или там `Dictionary<string, Tuple<object, Type>>` (для случая, когда возможен `null`). Для распознавания введённого значения вам наверняка пригодится [`Convert.ChangeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cytax8kf.aspx). Свойства вроде бы вовсе не нужны.

Comment: В дополнение к сказанному @VladD. Вместо Type можно TypeHandle использовать, ежели в рантайме всё происходить будет, ну, а также советую почитать про dynamic, так как такие действия как сложение, например, просто так не решаются на рандомных типах.

Comment: Спасибо! Читаю, изучаю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, вот так, если я правильно понял:

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = object.GetType().GetProperty("name");
var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(object, null);
```

Поддерживается во всех версиях .NET, судя по [документации](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/kz0a8sxy.aspx)

Comment: О! То что нужно!

Comment: Называется тоу чудо Reflection